# Update Timestamp field with the oldest record of fields within the row or those in a linked table

Tags: sql, db2

One table looks like this:

| TABLE A | Nullables |
| --- | --- |
| a_id | not nullable |
| create_timestamp | not nullable |
| edit_timestamp | nullable |
| closed_timestamp | nullable |
| last_mod_timestamp | not nullable |

The other one like this:

| TABLE B | Nullables |
| --- | --- |
| b_id | not nullable |
| table_a_fk | not nullable |
| create_timestamp | not nullable |

How would I set last_mod_timestamp to the oldest value of either (a.create_timestamp, a.edit_timestamp, a.closed_timestamp) or b.create_timestamp where b.table_a_fk = a.id?

Datatypes are all Timestamp.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A A
SET 
  last_mod_timestamp =
NULLIF
(
  MAX 
  (
    COALESCE (A.create_timestamp, '0001-01-01'::TIMESTAMP)
  , COALESCE (A.edit_timestamp, '0001-01-01'::TIMESTAMP)
  , COALESCE (A.closed_timestamp, '0001-01-01'::TIMESTAMP)
  , COALESCE (B.create_timestamp, '0001-01-01'::TIMESTAMP)
  )
, '0001-01-01'::TIMESTAMP
)
FROM
(
  SELECT table_a_fk, MAX (create_timestamp) create_timestamp
  FROM TABLE_B
  GROUP BY table_a_fk
) B
WHERE A.a_id = B.table_a_fk
```